# Type-safe "in" type guard

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards

I recently fixed a bug where we had code like this:

```
interface IBase { 
    sharedPropertyName: string; 
}
interface IFirst extends IBase { 
    assumedUnique: string;  
    unique1: string; 
}
interface ISecond extends IBase {  
    unique2: string; 
}
interface IThird extends IBase {  
    unique3: string; 
}

type PossibleInputs = IFirst | ISecond | IThird;
    
function getSharedProperty(obj: PossibleInputs): string | undefined {
    if ("assumedUnique" in obj) {
        return "version 1 of the function";
    }

    // do some operation using obj.sharedPropertyName
    return obj.sharedPropertyName;
}
```

This worked fine until someone accidentally removed `assumedUnique` from the definition of `IFirst` (you can hit a similar issue by adding `assumedUnique` to one of the other interfaces).

From that point, we started always going down the second code path, and no one noticed nor did the compiler enforce that the property name was meaningful.

To make this better, I made this function:

```
function safeIn<TExpected, TRest>(
    key: string & Exclude<keyof TExpected, keyof TRest>,
    obj: TExpected | TRest
): obj is TExpected {
    return (key as string) in obj;
}
```

This function has two goals:

1. Require that the given property name is a property that exists on the object
2. Require that the given property name can uniquely identify the object as a given type

Using the above implementation, I was able to rewrite the above as:

```
function getSharedProperty(obj: PossibleInputs): string | undefined {
    if (safeIn<IFirst, Exclude<PossibleInputs, IFirst>>("assumedUnique", obj)) {
        return "version 1 of the function";
    }

    // do some operation using obj.sharedPropertyName
    return obj.sharedPropertyName;
}
```

Now, if someone changes the interfaces it'll cause a compiler error.

We use this function generically now, including in long chains like this:

```
if (safeIn<PossibleType, FullUnionType>("propName", obj)) {
    // do something
} else if (safeIn<NextPossibleType, Exclude<typeof obj, NextPossibleType>>("nextPropName", obj)) {
    // do something
} else if (safeIn<NextNextPossibleType, Exclude<typeof obj, NextNextPossibleType>>("nextNextPropName", obj)) {
    // do something
}
// etc
```

Is there a way to write a generic function that doesn't require me to specify the second type parameter?

A successful implementation should be able to catch the following scenarios, with one or fewer type parameters to `safeIn` needing to be specified.

```
describe("safeIn", () => {
    interface IBase {
        sharedProperty: string;
    }
    interface IFirst extends IBase {
        assumedUnique: string;
        actualUnique1: string;
    }
    interface ISecond extends IBase {
        assumedUnique: string;
        actualUnique2: string;
    }
    interface IThird extends IBase {
        actualUnique3: string;
    }
    type PossibleProperties = IFirst | ISecond | IThird;
    const maker = (value: string, version: 1 | 2 | 3): PossibleProperties => {
        switch (version) {
            case 1:
                return { sharedProperty: value, assumedUnique: value, actualUnique1: value };
            case 2:
                return { sharedProperty: value, assumedUnique: value, actualUnique2: value };
            case 3:
                return { sharedProperty: value, actualUnique3: value };
        }
    }
    const compilesNever = (_: never): never => { throw "bad data"; };
    const firstObj = maker("whatever1", 1);
    const secondObj = maker("whatever2", 2);
    const thirdObj = maker("whatever3", 3);
    it("handles unique property", () => {
        expect(safeIn("actualUnique1", firstObj)).toBeTruthy();
        expect(safeIn("actualUnique1", secondObj)).toBeFalsy();
        expect(safeIn("actualUnique1", thirdObj)).toBeFalsy();
    });
    it("doesn't compile for non-unique properties", () => {
        expect(safeIn("assumedUnique", firstObj)).toBeTruthy();
        expect(safeIn("assumedUnique", secondObj)).toBeFalsy();
        expect(safeIn("assumedUnique", thirdObj)).toBeFalsy();
    });
    it("doesn't compile for missing properties", () => {
        expect(safeIn("fakeProperty", firstObj)).toBeTruthy();
        expect(safeIn("fakeProperty", secondObj)).toBeFalsy();
        expect(safeIn("fakeProperty", thirdObj)).toBeFalsy();
    });
    it("compiles type chain", () => {
        if (safeIn("actualUnique1", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else if (safeIn("actualUnique3", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else {
            compilesNever(thirdObj);
        }
    });
    it("doesn't compile invalid type chain", () => {
        if (safeIn("actualUnique1", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", thirdObj)) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        } else {
            compilesNever(thirdObj);
        }
    });
});
```

Some things I've tried (plus some variations of these, which I haven't included because they're very similar/I don't remember them exactly), none of which compile:

```
type SafeKey<TExpectedObject, TPossibleObject> =
    keyof TExpectedObject extends infer TKey
        ? TKey extends keyof TPossibleObject ? never : string & keyof TExpectedObject
        : never;

function autoSafeIn<TExpected, TRest extends TExpected>(
    obj: TRest | TExpected,
    key: SafeKey<TExpected, typeof obj>): obj is TExpected {
    return (key as string) in obj;
}

function autoSafeIn<TExpected>(
    obj: Record<Exclude<string, keyof TExpected>, unknown> | TExpected,
    key: SafeKey<TExpected, typeof obj>): obj is TExpected {
    return (key as string) in obj;
}

type SafeObject<TExpected> = keyof TExpected extends keyof infer TPossible ? Omit<TExpected, keyof TPossible> : TExpected;

function autoSafeIn<TExpected>(
    obj: SafeObject<TExpected> | object // or any, or unknown,
    key: string & keyof SafeObject<TExpected>
): obj is TExpected {
    return (key as string) in obj;
}
```

Comment: "Our real use case is a bit more complex, and ends up looking something like this:" can you provide a [mre] of what you're trying to solve without pseudocode/undeclared values or types?  Ideally I could paste your code directly into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6XdEm) and get to work implementing something without being distracted by errors.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPxo5W) would be my first attempt at implementing `safeIn()` but since I don't have a concrete example for `PossibleType`, `NextPossibleType`, etc, it can't be tested.

Comment: @jcalz This is a generic function we use in a lot of places, so the particular definition of `PossibleType` and friends isn't super relevant (and thus your implementation of `FilterByKnownKey` also wouldn't work). Edited to clarify that this needs to be generally applicable

Comment: I do believe my implementation of `safeIn()` is generally applicable.  Since  `FilterByKnownKey` doesn't involve any any specific types from your question I'm confused why you think it wouldn't work. Is the word `Known` the issue or is there something particular that leads you to that conclusion? If you could provide a concrete example of it not working, that would be ideal.  In order for me to test whether the implementation works well enough for your needs, I need some test cases. If you want a test case that looks like `if safeIn(...) else if safeIn (...) else`, then please provide one.

Comment: Oh, I misread your implementation (and I wasn't familiar with the `PropertyKey` type, so I just assumed that was one of the types I had used). I tried to clarify a bit. Right now, your implementation doesn't catch if the property name we assumed was unique is no longer unique (the `doSomething` case).

Comment: So, I'm looking at your new code, and it looks like in order to test I need to start messing with `doSomethingElse()` implementation and/or the definitions of your types.  Could you possibly provide your tests so that all I need to do is implement `safeIn()` and then they will pass or fail as-is?  Otherwise I'm spending my time developing the tests.

Comment: So, [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8KrAW) is another implementation that requires that the key be a known key of exactly one union member (assuming the unions are not composed of redundant entries like `{a: string} | {a: string, b: number}`). But without a provided test suite ‍♂️.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx1xN) is a possible test suite, but I don't know if it covers all the cases you care about.  Maybe you could check it/fix it and then [edit] your question to cover it?

Comment: One more thing, the code in your question has `object` a few times which seems to be a typo of `obj`.  Could you clean that up? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the `object` references, and added a test suite. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you probably want a `safeIn()` that works like this:

```
function safeIn<K extends UniqueKeys<T>, T extends object>(
  key: K,
  obj: T
): obj is FilterByKnownKey<T, K> {
  return key in obj;
}
```

Here, `obj` is some object type `T`, which will probably be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and `key` is of key type `K`.  The important pieces are that:

- `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `UniqueKeys<T>`, which are keys known to appear in exactly one member of the union of `T`; and
- the return type is the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `obj is FilterByKnownKey<T, K>`, where `FilterByKnownKey<T, K>` filters the `T` union to just those members known to have key `K`.

This means we need to implement `UniqueKeys<T>` and `FilterByKnownKey<T, K>`.  If we can accomplish this, then you shouldn't need to manually specify any type parameters when you call `safeIn()`; `K` and `T` will be inferred to be the apparent types of the supplied `key` and `obj` parameters.

---

So let's implement them. First, `UniqueKeys<T>`:

```
type AllKeys<T> =
  T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type UniqueKeys<T, U extends T = T> =
  T extends unknown ? Exclude<keyof T, AllKeys<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
```

Here we are using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split unions up into their members before processing them .

For example, `AllKeys<T>` is `T extends unknown ? keyof T : never`; this might look like the same thing as `keyof T`, but it isn't.  If `T` is `{a: 0} | {b: 0}` then `AllKeys<T>` evaluates to `keyof {a: 0} | keyof {b: 0}` which is `"a" | "b"`, while `keyof T` by itself would evaluate to `never` (since the union has no overlapping keys, so neither `"a"` nor `"b"` is known to be a key of `T`).  Thus, `AllKeys<T>` takes a union type `T` and returns a union of all keys which exist in any of the union members.

For your `PossibleProperties` type, this evaluates to:

```
type AllKeysOfPossibleProperties = AllKeys<PossibleProperties>
// type AllKeysOfPossibleProperties = "assumedUnique" | "actualUnique1" | 
//   "sharedProperty" | "actualUnique2" | "actualUnique3"
```

Now `UniqueKeys<T>` takes this a step further.  First, we need to hold onto the full union `T` while also splitting it up into members.  I use a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to copy the full `T` union into another type parameter `U`.  When we write `T extends unknown ? ... : never`, then `T` will be the individual members of the union, while `U` is the full union.  Thus `Exclude<U, T>` uses [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to represent all the other members of the union that are not `T`.  And therefore `Exclude<keyof T, AllKeys<Exclude U, T>>` is all the keys from the member of `T` which are not keys of any other members of the union `U`.  That is, it's just the keys which are unique to `T`.  And so the whole expression becomes a union of all the keys which are unique to some member of the union.

For your `PossibleProperties` type, this evaluates to:

```
type UniqueKeysOfPossibleProperties = UniqueKeys<PossibleProperties>
// type UniqueKeysOfPossibleProperties = "actualUnique1" | "actualUnique2" |
//   "actualUnique3"
```

So that worked.

---

Now for `FilterByKnownKey<T, K>`:

```
type FilterByKnownKey<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends unknown ? K extends keyof T ? T : never : never;
```

It's another distributive conditional type.  We split the union into members `T`, and for each member, we include it if and only if `K` is in `keyof T`.  For your `PossibleProperties` type and `"actualUnique2"`, this evaluates to:

```
type PossPropsFilteredByActualUnique2 =
  FilterByKnownKey<PossibleProperties, "actualUnique2">
// type PossPropsFilteredByActualUnique2 = ISecond
```

And that worked too.

---

Let's make sure it works as you want for your test cases.

```
declare const obj: PossibleProperties;
```

When we check a value of type `PossibleProperties` with `safeIn()`, we can use the key `"actualUnique1"` since it's a known key of only `IFirst`.  But we can't use `"assumedUnique"` or `"fakeProperty"` because they are either a known key of too many or too few of the members of `PossibileProperties`:

```
safeIn("actualUnique1", obj); // okay
safeIn("assumedUnique", obj); // error
safeIn("fakeProperty", obj); // error
```

Since `safeIn()` acts as a type guard on its `obj` input, you can use `if`/`else` statements to successively narrow the apparent type of `obj`.  And thus `UniqueKeys<typeof obj>` will themselves change:

```
if (safeIn("actualUnique1", obj)) {
} else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", obj)) {
} else if (safeIn("actualUnique3", obj)) {
} else { compilesNever(obj); }

if (safeIn("actualUnique1", obj)) {
} else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", obj)) {
} else if (safeIn("actualUnique2", obj)) { // error
} else { compilesNever(obj); }

if (safeIn("actualUnique2", obj)) {
} else if (safeIn("assumedUnique", obj)) { } // okay
```

We can eliminate `"actualUnique1"`, `"actualUnique2"`and `"actualUnique3"` in turn.  If you eliminate `"actualUnique2"` then it's an error to test against `"actualUnique2"` again, but it's fine to test against `"assumedUnique"`, since now it only exists on `IFirst` (as `ISecond` has been eliminated).

---

So this all looks good.  There are always caveats, so anyone using something like this is encouraged to test against their use cases and possible edge cases first.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#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-89q3o8AEThnqBo1lAAEzjAQGJsmYF2hB44AZy3L6nu7RgAhUGVrBRppph0FWtWuG1gBFKvucuGrp+bYXru177oetgpqeX6Xmh-Z3o+z7kcxH6bjR37sf+tgEVWKbwZBok4Zcqb4dhRGXCRZFqDA569ugsLFPqZRwDBCn6KmR6afC5SDNUrF0b+HGmFJ+l4feT4vipanXhphRaXQOl6SmhlDpOfoUsEAQoTAU40MqgJSBZP43gOFJhcqU46hAhQDgAcosR4fAA+jMWTggsWSEBiL4ci0XBQY82z+nQ2wgNsAFKDApKLjseyHB8tniQBpiAqCTWORwrDbGAwBtQcNCdcBkZgT1MB9QNz6KC0ChjbsE2dbSQjsRhvUvP1MCOctHCrZSYgfONHVdXBc19aCIauuQCDBlo52XZN124bJe3PKC92YqST0vW961XfJKYkT9f0PYDUDPayoUcMlqXoBlWQfAtzUUq9MAXaDH3gzdUP-Y9cPA7j71Td5YHffN+0k7D8NQiD7UE9TX23fTIaHUtCgraTTPoojyPdqjiwY-tTXkmdFP41ThE+Zzv0M0DsA43jrNTe2EagbhSvQ0LgODcNo3AEAA)